# Generate UUID for Flask endpoint on page load / or in Jinja method call

Tags: flask, jinja2

Is there a way to generate a unique UUID for a Flask endpoint (end of URL page address) only when the Flask blueprint actually generates the page?

The following Flask blueprint code does work for me:

```
@street_report_blueprint.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_streetreport(reportid=uuid.uuid4().hex):
    mainselection = request.form['MainlistRadios']
    return render_template('street_reports/street_report.jinja2', mainselection=mainselection, reportid=reportid)
```

`reportid` is generated as a default UUID value here in the parameter of the Flask method, and passes successfully to the webpage. (`{{ reportid }}` shows it there.)

But if I change the route to:

```
@street_report_blueprint.route('/<string:reportid>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

...then it doesn't work: Werkzeug throws a routing error along the lines of `Did you forget to include the UUID?`. I looked at
[Werkzeug's URL Routing docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/routing/) and checked SO and Google, so I hope nobody downvotes at least.

Or is there simple way to generate UUID and pass it inside the Jinja statement which calls the Blueprint method? Currently I have:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action = "{{ url_for('street_reports.get_streetreport') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: "Werkzeug throws routing error." What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I'll take a shot at answering it.

Unless I'm mistaken, a big difference between the two example snippets you posted above is that in the first one, the user is not required to specify a UUID when accessing that URL, while in the second snippet, some kind of string at the end of the URL *is* required.

It sounds like what you want is for the user to be able to navigate to a particular URL, say `www.website.com/thing/`, and if they just have the URL like that, they should have a unique UUID generated for them, and that UUID should be at the end of the URL they end up at, so something like `www.website.com/thing/d0248364-b3ec-481e-a725-2846c6e72576`, and if the user supplies that UUID themselves at the end of the URL (eg `www.website.com/thing/d0248364-b3ec-481e-a725-2846c6e72576`), they should just be brought to that page.

What I would do in that situation is to have two `GET` routes: one for the situation where the UUID has not yet been generated, and the other for the situation where the UUID is known. In the former situation (where the UUID needs to be created), I would create the UUID and then redirect them to the second route, which requires the UUID at the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, yes it is pretty much what I want thanks, but I don't know how I can get the uuid to generate on page load and also show in the URL when this page is first generated. Also, will be posting variables from a form to this page, so does that mean it will be POST request when the page first generated I think? And then GET perhaps if and when retrieved again. Werkzeug error is did you forget to include uuid, sorry another place now but pretty much this message I think.

Comment: "I don't know how I can get the uuid to generate on page load and also show in the URL when this page is first generated." As I explain in my answer, you will need to redirect the user to the new URL (the one that has the UUID in the URL).

Comment: "will be posting variables from a form to this page, so does that mean it will be POST request when the page first generated I think" Ok then the first route will be a POST route, and it will redirect to the second route, which will be a GET route and contain the UUID in the URL.

Comment: Thanks again @Nathan, I understood better reading 2nd time. But now I have: `@street_report_blueprint.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_streetreport(reportid=uuid.uuid4().hex): redirect(url_for('/<string:reportid>', reportid=reportid))` and `@street_report_blueprint.route('/<string:reportid>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_reportpage(reportid):   return render_template('street_reports/street_report.jinja2', reportid=reportid)` but 'could not build url for endpoint '/<string:reportid>' with values ['reportid']

Comment: Ok, my guess there is that you're trying to assign `reportid` to two different values in that second route (which should only be a `GET` route, by the way): the first is the variable passed in the URL itself (eg www.website.com/<reportid>), and the second is the parameter passed in the URL parameters (www.website.com/<reportid>?reportid=<reportid>).